# Transform structure of array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have data like -

```
var data = [{"DefaultZone":[{"key":"stream0","value":100},
                        {"key":"stream1","value":50},
                        {"key":"stream2","value":10}
                       ]},
        {"Zone 1":[{"key":"stream0","value":120},
                  {"key":"stream1","value":55},
                  {"key":"stream2","value":15}
                  ]}
       ]
```

and wanted to transform it like -

```
var data = [{"key": "stream0", "values":[{"x":"DefaultZone","y":100}, {"x":"Zone 1","y":120}]},
    {"key": "stream1", "values":[{"x":"DefaultZone","y":50}, {"x":"Zone 1","y":55}]},
    {"key": "stream2", "values":[{"x":"DefaultZone","y":10}, {"x":"Zone 1","y":15}]}
   ];
```

using JavaScript(ES6). Any help would be highly appreciated..

Comment: That's not JSON (JSON is a string format). I've edited your question to remove the references to "JSON", but you might like to [edit] it yourself to fix the syntax problems in your desired output (missing quotes, a missing comma).

Comment: What you show is a JavaScript object literal, not [JSON](http://www.json.org/). Is what you are showing actually what you have, or do you have actual JSON?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the first way that came to mind:

```js
var data = [{
  "DefaultZone": [
    { "key": "stream0", "value": 100 },
    { "key": "stream1", "value": 50 },
    { "key": "stream2", "value": 10 }]
}, { 
  "Zone 1": [
    { "key": "stream0", "value": 120 },
    { "key": "stream1", "value": 55 },
    { "key": "stream2", "value": 15 }]
}];

let working = data.reduce((p, c) => {
  let x = Object.keys(c)[0];
  c[x].forEach(v => {
    if (!p[v.key]) p[v.key] = [];
    p[v.key].push({ x: x, y: v.value });
  });
  return p;
}, {});

let output = Object.keys(working).map(v => ({ key: v, values: working[v] }));

console.log(output);
```

Further reading:

- [the array `.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [the `Object.keys()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [the array `.forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ForEach)
- [the array `.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map)

Answer (score 0):

Although I like [nnnnnn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) answer, here is another one, using only [the Object.keys() method:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var data = [{
    "DefaultZone": [{
        "key": "stream0",
        "value": 100
    }, {
        "key": "stream1",
        "value": 50
    }, {
        "key": "stream2",
        "value": 10
    }]
}, {
    "Zone 1": [{
        "key": "stream0",
        "value": 120
    }, {
        "key": "stream1",
        "value": 55
    }, {
        "key": "stream2",
        "value": 15
    }]
}]

final = {}
data.forEach(function(x) {
    Object.keys(x).forEach(function(y) {
        x[y].forEach(function(z) {
            if (!final[z['key']]) final[z['key']] = [];
            final[z['key']].push({
                'x': y,
                'y': z['value']
            })
        })
    })
})
answer = []
Object.keys(final).forEach(function(x) {
    answer.push({
        'key': x,
        values: final[x]
    })
})
console.log(answer)
```